# Stored Proc to insert into 3 tables using IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a form which must get inserted into 3 tables. I have created a stored proc (that is not correct).

3 tables: 
1. dbo.Client (ClientID, ClientName, *AddressID*) 
2. dbo.Contact (AddressID, Addressline1, Add2, *CityID* ) CityID comes from Dropdownlist.
3. dbo.PointOfCContact (POCID, FirstName, ...)

My Stored proc..

```
Create PROCEDURE sp_Clientdetails(
    @ClientName varchar(50),

    @Addressline1   varchar(50),
    @Addressline2   varchar(50),
    @CityID INT,

    @Firstname  varchar(50),
    @LastName   varchar(50),
    @Middlename  varchar(50),
    @Mob1 numeric(10,0),
    @Mob2 numeric(10,0),
    @Email1 varchar(50),
    @Email2 varchar(50),
    @phone varchar(50),
    @Extention INT  
    )
AS
DECLARE @AddressID int, @ClientID int, @POCID int;

Set NOCOUNT OFF

BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF NOT EXISTS(Select 1 FROM dbo.Contact Where AddressID=@AddressID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Contact VALUES (@Addressline1, @Addressline2, @CityID);
    SET @AddressID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    SET @CityID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
ELSE
    Select AddressID = @AddressID From dbo.Contact Where AddressID=@AddressID;

IF NOT EXISTS(Select 1 FROM dbo.Client Where ClientID=@ClientID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Client VALUES (@ClientID, @AddressID, @CityID);
    SET @ClientID= SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
ELSE
    Select ClientID = @ClientID From dbo.Client Where ClientID = @ClientID;

Insert into dbo.PointOfCContact VALUES (@Firstname, @LastName, @Middlename, @Mob1, @Mob2,
 @Email1, @Email2, @phone, @Extention);
SET @POCID= SCOPE_IDENTITY();

COMMIT
```

Getting an error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

on     `INSERT INTO dbo.Contact VALUES (@Addressline1, @Addressline2, @CityID);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify your column names

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Contact (Address1, Adddres2, CityID) 
VALUES (@Addressline1, @Addressline2, @CityID);

....

INSERT INTO dbo.Client (ClientID, AddressID, CityID)
VALUES (@ClientID, @AddressID, @CityID);
```

etc

Better, you could use the `MERGE` syntax
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: `INSERT INTO dbo.Contact (Address1, Adddres2, CityID) 
VALUES (@Addressline1, @Addressline2, @CityID);
SET @AddressID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO dbo.Client (ClientID, AddressID, CityID)
VALUES (@ClientID, @AddressID, @CityID); `

U mean like this?

Comment: @Girish Yes. You should add the column names to all the INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0):

You must add structure table; add columns to table

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Contact (Address1, Adddres2, CityID) VALUES (@Addressline1, @Addressline2, @CityID);
```